# Camshaft sinks too much into block: add spacer washer at its end?

Tags: camshaft

While I'm rebuilding my old Skoda Estelle engine I got this new issue: I have found a better engine block that I want to use, however the camshaft I have from the other block, sinks too much when I put it in its place. It goes down for about 3 or 4 mm. When I look to the camshaft from the crankcase perspective, I see it shifted towards the block's rear in all its seats.

The parts catalog for this engine doesn't show a spacer washer in any of the camshaft extremes. The block has its sheet metal plug there.

So question is: can I add a spacer washer inside the rearmost camshaft seat, so it wedges the camshaft out and put it in the right place? It is an aluminum block, but I guess a mild steel washer (that I can fabricate with the needed precision) may do, since it will friction against the camshaft tail there.

Any suggestions?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I need two images: 1) a broader view of the block; 2) the cam gear face where it matches the block. I don't know about this case, but many cam gears are made to ride on the front of the block, which keeps the cam positioned. I'm not sure about your Skoda. Interesting dilemma! Hope we can help.

Comment: If you end up adding *something*, consider using a Torrington bearing instead of a washer.

Comment: That, my friend, will be a hell of adventure to find one here :)

Comment: In fact, thinking it better: the camshaft will move to its position, when the gears and the distribution gear on top of it gets secured, when the gears are pressed in and the triangle washer gets secured as well, i.e, when everything gets installed. However, this will move the camshaft to its position, the missing 4mm at its rear extreme will remain there. I wonder if that's nonsense, or if I should still place a washer there.

Comment: Is this a roller cam or a regular lifter cam?

Comment: It is lifter one, the system has followers, rods and the rockers in the head

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of camshafts. Roller cams and everything else solid lifter.

Solid cams effectively float. They are not mounted solidly. Instead the taper of lobes pushes the cam against and end plate. Generally the plate that bolts in the cam also works as the stop. The full endplay of the cam is irrelevant as long as the mounting plate places the cam in the correct possition.

[image]

In a roller cam the lobe can not be tapered bacause of the roller lifter. In this type or setup the full back and forth end play needs to be controlled. These meathods are more complicated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Question solved! It is like that by design. I checked two more blocks with their respective camshafts and this one as well: the camshafts are secured in place by a washer against the block and the sprocket over it. When everything is in place and tight, the camshafts won't have a way to move into the block. The remaining space at the rear of it may be for oiling, since these camshafts have a drill in the rear extreme and passing through it, looping then to the rear seat.